# CKEditor Browse Server Button Is Shown in Link Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I use ckeditor 4 in my web app.

I'm struggling two problems for a few hours. I'v setup ckeditor by the following code:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('editor',
            {
                language: 'en',
                height: 500,
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/site/admin.File.listForEditor'
            }
            , '');
```

It seems to be ok and listForEditor page will be loaded on toolbar image button clicked.

My problems:

1. I don't know why 'Browse Server' button is shown in 'Link' tab of Image Properties dialog instead of 'Image Info' tab. So, when I choose an image file from my custom file finder, it's url will be added to 'Link' tab url input.

[image]

2. When I choose an image file, if I need to add another file, it's not work. It seems the previous value is cached in editor instance, and by refreshing the page it works ok :|